# Trying to redirect directory to https but getting double URL segment on return

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, expressionengine

I'm trying to redirect one directory on my site to https. The directory is not really a directory at all because the site's dynamic. I'm using ExpressionEngine as the CMS.

I already have a few lines in my .htaccess file to remove the index.php ExpressionEngine adds to all of its urls.

Here's what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/store/$1 [R,L]

        # Removes index.php
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I visit, http://mysite.com/store/, it returns https://mysite.com/store/store/.

I think it might have to do with the following:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The above line has a question mark after the index.php because I was getting a "No input file" error, and that was the recommended fix.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note, you can post future EE questions on the beta site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/store/$1 [R,L]
```

to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Now it works. Here's the full code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

        # Removes index.php
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store
```

Should have a `!` in front of "store":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !store
```

because you *don't* want it to redirect if the URI is already `/store`.

Comment: Hey Jon. Tried this out, and it returned: https://mysite.com/store/index.php?/store/